# Are squares of independent random variables independent?

Tags: statistics, random

If X and Y are independent random variables both with the same mean (0) and variance, how about $X^2$ and $Y^2$? I tried calculating E($X^2Y^2$)-E($X^2$)E($Y^2$) but haven't been able to get anywhere.

Comment: They must be independent. How could you calculate $E(X^2Y^2)$?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then so are $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ for (measurable) functions $g(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$. Means and variances don't come into the picture and your attempted calculation of $\text{cov}(X^2,Y^2)$ will not prove independence even though the covariance will turn out to be $0$.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful to know.

Comment: @Dilip: You could post that as an answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: @DilipSarwate what's measurable in elem probability? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944284/prove-that-for-independent-random-variables-x-i-we-have-f-ix-i-are-indepe

Comment: @joriki what's measurable in elem probability? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944284/prove-that-for-independent-random-variables-x-i-we-have-f-ix-i-are-indepe

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per joriki's suggestion, my comment (with additional information)
is posted as an answer.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then so are $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ independent
random variables for (measurable) functions $g(⋅)$ and $h(⋅)$. In particular,
$X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent random variables if $X$ and $Y$
are independent random variables.  Means and variances don't come into the picture at all, and your attempted calculation of 
$\text{cov}(X^2,Y^2)$ will not prove independence even though the 
covariance will turn out to be $0$.

Comment: "In particular, $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent random variables if $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent random variables." I am 99% sure that this should read "In particular, $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent random variables if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables"?

Comment: @Silverfish You are absolutely correct.  Thanks for proof-reading carefully.  I have corrected the typos.

Comment: What's 'measurable' in elementary probability? see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944284/prove-that-for-independent-random-variables-x-i-we-have-f-ix-i-are-indepe