# If $A$ and $\bar{X}$ are independent, then so are $S^2$ and $\bar{X}$ independent

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a question about a question in the following link:
[Proof of the independence of the sample mean and sample variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47350/proof-of-the-independence-of-the-sample-mean-and-sample-variance)
Here $( X_{2}-\bar{X},X_{3}-\bar{X},\cdots,X_{n}-\bar{X}) =A$, $S^2$ the estimator of the variance and $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d. $N(\mu, \sigma)$. In the link it says that if $A$ and $\bar{X}$ are independent, then so are $S^2$ and $\bar{X}$. I've thought about this very long but I can't find out why. I need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $X, Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$ are independent random variables, then so are $X$ and $g(Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n)$ for any (measurable) function $g$. Apply 
this to your question after noting that $S^2$ is a function of the $n$ random variables $X_i−\bar{X}$. See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/220510/15941).

The harder part of problem is in first
proving that $A$ and $\bar{X}$ are independent
random variables, which is true for i.i.d. normal random variables 
$X_i$ but not necessarily true for other distributions.