# Second moment of chi squared distribution

Tags: statistics

I've got difficulties in computing the second momentum of chi squared.

Chi squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom is the sum of $n$ independent distributions $X^2$, where $X \sim N(0;1)$.

We know that the fourth momentum of each $X_i$ is $3$.

So, mark $\chi^2 = C$, and 
$$E(C^2) = E\left[ \left(\sum X^2\right)^2 \right] = \sum E\left[X^4\right] = 3n$$
where the penultimate equality is due to $X$s being iid and linearity of E-operator.

The correct answer is $n^2 +2n$, so there is something wrong with the above calculation, but I just can't spot what it is. (Please note that I'm not claiming that $\left(\sum x^2 \right)^ 2 = \sum x^4$ in general. Here it should hold however, since the $X$s are independent, right?)

Comment: I have edited your question to make use of $\LaTeX$ math formatting.  Please confirm that I have not misrepresented your question by editing. :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks and sorry. No misrepresentation there! :)

Comment: That's good to hear.  And no need to apologize--LaTeX/MathJax can take a bit to get used to.  Here's the "[quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)" guide for this site.  (Unfortunately, I don't know statistics, so I can't help with your question...)

Comment: Independence would suggest $E[X_i^2 X_j^2] = E[X_i^2]E[X_j^2]$ for $i \not = j$ but that is unlikely to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

$E\left[ \left(\sum_i X_i^2\right)^2 \right] = E\left[ \sum_i X_i^4 \right] + E\left[ \sum_i \sum_{j \not = i}X_i^2 X_j^2 \right] = 3n+n(n-1)$

Answer (score 1):

Your argument in parentheses is wrong. Rather, we always have, regardless of independence, that

$$(\sum X^2)^2=\sum_i X_i^4+2\sum_{i<j}X^2_iX^2_j$$

The independence helps when we take expectations. Since the X's are independent we have $$E[X_iX_j]=E[X_i]E[X_j]$$

We also have that because the X's are independent, so are their squares. (See 
[Are squares of independent random variables independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220377/are-squares-of-independent-random-variables-independent).)
Therefore, combining the two previous facts, taking expectations of the above sum gives $$3n+2\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=3n+n^2-n=n^2+2n$$

Comment: Ok, now I got it! I misremembered independence to mean that E[XY] = 0. Thanks for your answers. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider upvoting them.